# How to calculate decimal value

Tags: solidity, remix

problem with retrieving decimal value.

Example:

```
ufixed8x2 profit = 0;
uint256 amount = 5000000; //msg.value;
 uint256 constant private PERCENT_DIVIDER = 1; 

profit= ufixed8x2(amount.div(24).div(60).div(60).mul(PERCENT_DIVIDER).div(100));
```

Output is 0 - wrong must be 0.57

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `uint256 amount = 5000000`,

the type of the expression `amount.div(24).div(60).div(60).mul(1)` is `uint256`,

and its value is `57`.

And when you divide `uint256(57)` by `100`, the result is obviously `0`.

I don't know anything about the type `ufixed8x2`, but assuming that it handles arithmetic operations correctly, you should cast the intermediate result of `57` to this type before dividing it by `100`.

In other words, change this:

```
profit = ufixed8x2(amount.div(24).div(60).div(60).mul(PERCENT_DIVIDER).div(100));
```

To this:

```
profit = ufixed8x2(amount.div(24).div(60).div(60).mul(PERCENT_DIVIDER)).div(100);
```

At least in other strongly-typed languages, this method does the job.

If the `div` method is not implemented for the `ufixed8x2` type, then you can either implement it for this type, or just replace it with a simple `/` (which you may as well do for all the other occurrences of this method in your code, since there is no benefit in calling it with a constant value - it is a pure waste of gas).